# Org with a lot of customizations

Tags: appexchange, metadata

I need a large org with more than 5K or 10K components. All the components must be accessible so that we can retrieve them via the metadata API. How can I find such an org?

I tried to install all the unmanaged packages from appexchange, but most of those packages are very old and have compilation errors.

Comment: Kevin, you may get more response if you explain what your actual goal is, what are you trying to do or test ?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a developer org with that limit available, simply create a couple of example components, retrieve their XML and then write a script to iterate and duplicate this before re-uploading.